# Get lat/lon in degrees using PostGIS

Tags: postgis-1.5

I downloaded the shape file https://dati.comune.milano.it/media/rdp/comunemilano/dati/MM_FERMATE.7z, it represents the Milan's subway stations. I used ogrinfo to output the shapefile's summary and guess the SRID:

```
$ ogrinfo -summary MM_FERMATE.shp MM_FERMATE

INFO: Open of `MM_FERMATE.shp'
  using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: MM_FERMATE
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 100
Extent: (1506722.964600, 5027236.460200) - (1534186.769400, 5043728.155000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["Monte_Mario_Italy_zone_1",
GEOGCS["GCS_Monte Mario",
    DATUM["Monte_Mario",
    SPHEROID["International_1924",6378388,297]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",1500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["Meter",1]]
ID: Integer (10.0)
FERMATA: String (100.0)
N_ARCHI: Integer (10.0)
```

Then I loaded the data in PostgreSQL:

```
shp2pgsql -s 3003 MM_FERMATE.shp | psql -d gis_sample
```

Finally I tried to convert "the_geom" field in degrees but I always got the same results.

Output using st_astext function:

```
gis_sample=# select st_astext(the_geom) from mm_fermate where n_archi = 4;
    st_astext             
----------------------------------
POINT(1515086.3214 5037713.221)
POINT(1516846.3194 5036826.4702)
POINT(1515864.6252 5036806.3372)
POINT(1514766.6816 5034612.3064)
POINT(1513860.5034 5034993.1312)
(5 rows)
```

Output using st_asewkt:

```
gis_sample=# select st_asewkt(the_geom) from mm_fermate where n_archi = 4;
        st_asewkt                  
--------------------------------------------
SRID=3003;POINT(1515086.3214 5037713.221)
SRID=3003;POINT(1516846.3194 5036826.4702)
SRID=3003;POINT(1515864.6252 5036806.3372)
SRID=3003;POINT(1514766.6816 5034612.3064)
SRID=3003;POINT(1513860.5034 5034993.1312)
(5 rows)
```

How can I get the lat/lon in degrees?

Below there's my PostGIS version:

```
gis_sample=# select PostGIS_Full_Version ();
                    postgis_full_version                                          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.8.0" USE_STATS
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 4):

The ST_Transform function takes the desired coordinate system as the second parameter - see ST_Transform [page](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) for PostGis.

```
untested example ..

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(the_geom,4326)) As wgs_geom;
```

Comment: If PostGIS 2.x is available and pretty lat/long output is desired, [ST_AsLatLonText](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsLatLonText.html) can be used in place of ST_AsText.